# Adding favicon to RSS feed

Tags: rss, mezzanine

Within [Messanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/), what is the best way to add a favicon to your site rss feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The favicon discovery which works with any HTML page should work with RSS as well ;) Juts pout it in `/favicon.ico` under the host that serves the RSS feed.

Comment: That worked!  I had to hack nginx to rewrite the url to point to the correct place but that does work.  Thank you!

Comment: That's the correct approach - you'll see the same in Mezzanine's default nginx config: https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/project_template/deploy/nginx.conf#L43

Comment: What if on my web server I have an RSS filter script and want to retain the original favicons instead of each filtered feed getting my own web domain's favicon?

Comment: @kriegaex that's a question worthy of its own page.

Comment: @MattSephton, yes. The way I solved it last year was to create a subdomain for each feed and then in `.htaccess` to add one pair of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` which makes Apache fetch `favicon.ico` from the respective original URL. If you need more details, let me know.

Comment: @kriegaex yes, would appreciate some further details. on twitter and github I am: gingerbeardman